# Percentage value is not correct

Tags: html, css, asp.net, easypie

I have designed a page in asp.net and it has to display the percentage 100% or less than that but it is more than 100% . I don't know whether it is design issue or code .

[image: My page]

Here is my code, sorry I forgot to add it before. I can't provide the css code as it's very complex. Please help I don't understand how to explain my problem

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Profile Completeness</td>
        <td>Resume Type</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="ResumeData" style="border: 1px">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none">
  <table>
    <tr id="ResumeId" class="h4">
      <td id="Sno"></td>
      <td id="Resume">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Nob" class="center">
        <div class="easy-pie-chart percentage easyPieChart divProCompleted" data-percent="10" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; color: rgb(209, 91, 71);">
          <span class="percent bigger-150 SpnProComplete">
                            10
                        </span>%
          <canvas width="40" height="40"></canvas>
          <canvas width="40" height="40"></canvas>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can u please post some code

Comment: Please Provide Your Code

Comment: you can add max-width:100%; and overflow:auto;

Comment: if you give some code.. It will be easy to solve.. And can check where you are going wrong..

Comment: forgot your code?

Comment: But the image that you attached here doesn't seem to have more than 100%

Comment: i think he meant the td content that shows 102%

Comment: @Kanchan Sharma , is your problem that your pie chart displays 102% ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved all I had to do is to remove that hard coded value supplied to the tag

```
       <span class="percent bigger-150 SpnProComplete">
          10  </span>
```

Every time a value comes to it this 10 gets added to it so it shows wrong percentage..
as my actual percentage was 92% but it got incremented by 10 and became 102%.
All I have to do is to pass 0 instead of 10.
Thanks to all for valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

use this code will helpfull in designing. this code work sure

```html
<div style="height:200px; Width:60%; background-color:green;">
    vijay chaudhary
</div>

<div style="height:200px; Width:100%; background-color:green;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                vijay
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @snit80 It sets the first div to 60% of the browsers' width, and the second div to 100% of the browsers' width. Using percentage makes the page responsive to the size of the screen it's displayed on.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I guess the problem that OP is having is completely different